# Calculate the percentiles for how many times a file id from table1 exists in table2?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables like this:

table1

```
email,                   file_id
useremail1@mydomain.com, qUvGRdixBN
useremail2@mydomain.com, aIirUAqKwm
useremail3@mydomain.com, njeOMonYyb
```

table2

```
file_id,    event_name
qUvGRdixBN, download
aIirUAqKwm, view
njeOMonYyb, print
```

From which I need to know 1) the email addresses with most number of files (regardless of activity in table2), or email addresses with more than X files 2) For the users which meet the previous criteria, need to know total number of files they have from table1, number of files without any events in table2, and ideally some percentiles like min/max and .01 .1 .5 .9 .95.  The goal here is to chart/graph the results to illustrate the accounts and how much log activity there is on the files they own compared to total number of files they own.

Something like this as an output would be ideal:

output_table

```
email, total_num_files, total_num_files_no_logs, percentile_min, percentile_max, percentile_05, ...
```

To identify the top 100 users I came up with the followong:

```
SELECT email, count(distinct(file_id)) numFiles
FROM `table1` 
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY numFiles DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Then to identify files with no log activity I saved that first one as a view and created a second query like this:

```
WITH top_100_users AS (
  SELECT email
  FROM `top_100_fileowners_view`
)
SELECT u.email, f.file_id, f.name, f.mimeType
FROM top_100_users u
LEFT JOIN `table1` f
ON f.email = u.email
LEFT JOIN `table2` a
ON a.file_id = f.file_id
WHERE a.drive.doc_id is null
```

This tells me how many files users with most number of files have with no log activity in table2, but as a separate table as the first query.  Now to add in percentiles and I'm totally lost.  Suspect that to get where I'm at was probably not the most efficient sql.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what are the percentages you want to calculate ?

Comment: Yeah sorry it wasn't clear.  Let's say user1@mydomain.com owns 100 files.  10 of them don't appear in the logs at all, 20 of them appear in the logs 1 time, and 10 of them appear in the logs 125 times.  So, out of all the files, would like to know the percentage of files which exist in the logs 0 times or more.  Or more specifically at the 10th percentile for a given user, the files show in the logs how many times?  Does that make more sense?

Comment: by logs you mean table 2,  correct?

Comment: I have written a script which I believe it will help you visualize the percentiles you want. I will post it as an answer. Then, if needed, I can update the answer with the percentages you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I was able to write a SQL code in BigQuery to create a general table which will help you visualize your percentiles.

I followed some of the steps you posted in your question description. However, I worked with temp tables.

The data I used to reproduce the case is as follows:

- **Table 1:** *t1email* (notice that I have added some data for further clarification)

[image]

- **Table 2:** *t2logs* (notice that I have added some data for further clarification)

[image]

The script I wrote is as follows:

```
with t1_count as (
SELECT  email , count(file_id) as file_count
FROM `test-proj-261014.sample.t1email` as a
group by email
#you can use filter here "more thgan X files in count"
),

t2_count as (
SELECT email, file_id, COUNT(file_id) as file_count2 
FROM (SELECT t1.email, t2.file_id, FROM `test-proj-261014.sample.t2logs`t2 LEFT JOIN `test-proj-261014.sample.t1email` t1 ON t1.file_id = t2.file_id  )  
GROUP BY file_id, email
),

numberFiles_fromt1 as (
select t1.email,t2.file_id 
FROM `test-proj-261014.sample.t1email`t1 INNER JOIN `test-proj-261014.sample.t2logs` t2 ON t1.file_id=t2.file_id
), 

filesWithoutEvent_t2 as (
SELECT t1.* from `test-proj-261014.sample.t1email`t1 LEFT JOIN `test-proj-261014.sample.t2logs`t2 ON t1.file_id=t2.file_id WHERE t2.file_id IS NULL
)

SELECT t1.email, COALESCE(t1.file_id,t2.file_id) as file_id,file_count, file_count2  
FROM `test-proj-261014.sample.t1email` t1 FULL JOIN `test-proj-261014.sample.t2logs` t2 ON t1.file_id=t2.file_id
LEFT JOIN t1_count ON t1_count.email=t1.email
LEFT JOIN t2_count ON t2_count.file_id = t2.file_id 
ORDER BY email
#where email is null file is not in table1, just in the logs
#where file_count2 is null, file_id is not in the logs
#where file_count is null, file_id is not in the table1
#you can see multiple repeated emails, it is because they have diferent file count in t2logs, this would help you calculate more accurate percentiles.
```

And the output:

[image]

As written in the comments within the code, there are duplicate emails in the final table because the column *file_count* in **table1** (t1email) differs from *file_count2* in **table2** (t2logs). It happens, because *file_count2* is a different metric that accounts for each individual file . Furtheremore, the null values also gives us valuable information, for instance, when email is null file is not in **table1**, just in the logs. Nevertheless, you can use WHERE filters in order to select and calculate the desired percentiles based in the columns ***file_count*** and ***file_count2***.

As stated in the comment section, if needed, I can upload the answer with the percentiles you aim to calculate.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping.  Is there a way to do this so that the output table doesn't have file_id as a column, and only one row per email?  What i need to know is total files per email, and how frequently that user's files appear in table2.

Comment: To drop file_id, you just do not select it in the last select statement. In my understanding, if you count the files grouping them by email, you are counting different files ( table 1). On the other hand, if you count the files in table 2, you group them by file. In the above code, for example, **useremail3** has 3 files in table 1. However,  **njeOMonYya** appears just once in table 2, while **njeOMonYyc* does not appear in table 2.

Comment: So, continuing, if you want to know the frequency, you could count how many files which the user have in table 2 and then divide it by the count resulted from table 1. For example, **useremail3** has the total of 3 files and 2 of them are in table 2. Thus, 2/3 = 0,666 = 66,6% of this user's files appears in table 2. Is this the logic you want ? If yes, do you need help with the code?